# Tie an action to a state change in pure React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Learning React so might be a bit nooby question. Consider this code:

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Container />
  }
}

class Container extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      isOn: false
    }
    this.handleToggle = this.handleToggle.bind(this);
  }

  handleToggle(on) {
    this.setState({
      isOn: on
    });
  }

  render() {
    return ( 
      <div>
      <p>
        {this.state.isOn ? 'on' : 'off'}
      </p>
      <MyButton handleToggle={this.handleToggle} />
        </div>
    );
  }
}


class MyButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pressed: false
    }
    this.handleButtonToggle = this.handleButtonToggle.bind(this);
  }


  handleButtonToggle() {
    const on = !this.state.pressed
    this.setState({
      pressed: on
    });
    this.props.handleToggle(on);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleButtonToggle}>
          {this.state.pressed ? "pressed" : "depressed"}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

As you can see currently when the button inside the Container is clicked `handleButtonToggle()` is fired which changes the state of the button itself and then calls a function to change the state of the parent Container. Is this the React way to do it? At the moment Container state is changed when the function `handleButtonToggle` is fired.  Ideally I would want Container state to be dependent on MyButton **state** directly (cuz maybe in future there will be ways to set button state other than through `handleButtonToggle`, and I don't want to manually call `this.props.handleToggle` every time the state changes.). In other words is there a way to do something like `this.props.handleToggle(this.state.pressed)` in the button component when its state changes.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/redFur/pen/KmLXKP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either pass a callback as the second argument to [`setState`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate) or implement [`componentDidUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) on your component to wait for state changes. The smallest change would be the former:

```
handleButtonToggle() {
  const on = !this.state.pressed
  this.setState({
    pressed: on
  }, () => {
    this.props.handleToggle(on);
  });
}
```

or with `componentDidUpdate`:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevState.on !== this.state.on) {
    this.props.handleToggle(this.state.on);
  }
}
```

Comment: The latter version looks like what I am looking for!

Answer (score 2):

After reviewing the code, a better way to write the Button component is to make it a controlled component. If the container component requires to maintain the pressed state, a controlled button component would receive the pressed state from the container component as props.

```
 <MyButton pressed={this.state.pressed} onToggle={this.handleToggle} />
```

And the render method of the Button component should be:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.props.onToggle}>
          {this.props.pressed ? "pressed" : "depressed"}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

The actual button toggle will be done in the handleToggle method of the container component:

```
 handleButtonToggle() {
    let { pressed } = this.state;
    pressed = !pressed;
    this.setState({
      pressed
    });
  }
```

Comment: I was considering this version too. Why would you say it's better? Is this because this way the button state reflects the container state in a more direct way?

Comment: If state needs to be maintained by parent component, this version is better. However, if you want a generic component, allowing both controlled (pressed) and uncontrolled (defaultPressed) is a good option.

Comment: Yes I want a generic button which state can be set only by itself.

Comment: Makes sense. Uncontrolled but generic. Usually, on form edits,  a default value is passed for uncontrolled components. Recommend a defaultPressed prop which is passed by the parent.

Comment: Would I set this default value in the constructor?

Comment: yes, it comes as props. In the constructor, initialise the state using `this.state = { pressed: props.defaultPressed };`

Answer (score -1):

Here is a working codepen: https://codepen.io/damien-monni/pen/XRwewV.
I tried to keep as much as I can of your code so you can focus on really needed changes.

You need to create a [controlled component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components). The state of your button will be stored in the container and pass by props to the child MyButton component.

```
/*
 * A simple React component
 */
class Application extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Container />
  }
}

class Container extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      isOn: false
    }
    this.handleToggle = this.handleToggle.bind(this);
  }

  handleToggle() {
    this.setState({
      isOn: !this.state.isOn
    });
  }

  render() {
    return ( 
      <div>
      <p>
        {this.state.isOn ? 'on' : 'off'}
      </p>
      <MyButton pressed={this.state.isOn} handleToggle={this.handleToggle} />
        </div>
    );
  }
}


class MyButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pressed: this.props.pressed
    }
    this.handleButtonToggle = this.handleButtonToggle.bind(this);
  }


  handleButtonToggle() {
    this.props.handleToggle();
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.pressed !== this.props.pressed) {
      this.setState({ pressed: nextProps.pressed });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleButtonToggle}>
          {this.state.pressed ? "pressed" : "depressed"}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


/*
 * Render the above component into the div#app
 */

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

You need to do it because you want to share a state between two of your components. This is [documented here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

I let you look at the codepen and ask your questions about it. ;)

Comment: This is not what I am asking.